# JPlayer adding background-color to div, why?

Tags: jquery, html, background-color, jplayer, css-frameworks

I use skeleton css framework with JPlayer and I have this html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="sixteen columns">
    <div id="jquery_jplayer_1"></div>
    <div id="page-title">
        <h2><?php echo $this->input('page-title', array('width' => 300)); ?></h2>
        <div id="bolded-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div should be hidden, but it has a black background-color:

Firbug shows:

```
element.style {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

and:

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
```

Why is that? I also cant override it with my own styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a default setting, you can set the background in the plugin settings like this:

```
  jPlayer({backgroundColor:"#cccccc"});
```

you can find the other settings here: 
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-backgroundColor